# Incremental GroupBy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do incremental groupby and ranking in pandas.

Sample DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(7,3)),columns=["a","b","c"])
df["d1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Mango","Mango","Mango","Apple"]
df["d2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df


    a   b   c     d1      d2     date
0   7   1   4   Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   3   7   6   Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   9   6   9   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   0   5   8   Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
4   4   6   7   Mango   lemon   2002-02-01
5   4   3   8   Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
6   0   2   8   Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
```

Trying to  incremental Group by `d1` and rank every row of column `d1` based on another column `c`.

For loc `[0,"d1"]`, the value `Apple` will be rank `0` since there is only row and no comparison exits.

For loc `[1,"d1"]` , the value `Mango` will be `1` because considering the first two rows the corresponding value of `Apple` in column `C`, i.e value of `[0,"c"]` is `4` (Apple) and the value of `[1,"C"]` is `6` (for Mango) so Mango has higher rank in this sliced DF

For loc `[2,"d1"]` , the value `Apple` will be `1` because considering the first three rows the corresponding value of `Apple` in column `C`, i.e value of `[0,"c"]` is `4` (Apple) and the value of `[1,"C"]` is `6` (for Mango), the value of `[2,"c"]` is `9` (Apple) so the average of 2 values for `Apple` is `(4+9)/2 =6.5` and the value for `Mango`is `6` so `Apple` will be rank `1`.

Following the same pattern incrementally and updating the value of column `d1` at the last index of the incrementally sliced DF.

Expected values for column `d1`:

```
0
1
1
1 => since for Apple (4+9)/2 and for Mango (6+8)/2
1 => since for Apple (4+9)/2 and for Mango (6+8+7)/3
1 => since for Apple (4+9)/2 and for Mango (6+8+7+8)/4
0 => since for Apple (4+9+8)/2 and for Mango (6+8+7+8)/4
```

I can do this in a for loop by slicing iteratively `df[:i]`, but for large DFs this is taking forever, any suggestions on a more pandas based approach will be great.

Applying the first solution to the following random DF:

```
    a   b   c     d1       d2    date
0   7   1   19  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   3   7   17  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   9   6   4   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   0   5   15  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
4   4   6   8   Mango   lemon   2002-02-01
5   4   3   1   Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
6   2   2   14  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
7   5   15  10  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
8   1   2   10  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
9   2   1   12  Apple   Orange  2002-02-01
```

I get the following values for `d1`:

```
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
1
0
```

the last value is wrong because at that point the value of `Apple` is `12.33` (19+4+15+14+10+12)/6 and `Mango` is `9` (17+8+1+10)/4 so the last value of `d1` should be `1`.

Comment: I don't know if I get what you want, but it looks like the `expanding` function would help. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html

Comment: In very last line "Mango is 9  (17+8+1+10)/4 "  What happened to the 15 on index 3?   Shouldn't that be 17+15+8+1+10 / 5?

Comment: @ScottBoston my bad , I forgot to edit column ```d1```, now i have edited it correctly. Now if you check last value is not correct as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated for second dataframe:

```
   a   b   c     d1       d2    date
0   7   1   19  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   3   7   17  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   9   6   4   Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   0   5   15  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
4   4   6   8   Mango   lemon   2002-02-01
5   4   3   1   Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
6   2   2   14  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
7   5   15  10  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
8   1   2   10  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
9   2   1   12  Apple   Orange  2002-02-01

s = df.groupby('d1')['c'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1)
```

Outputs:

```
Apple  0    19.000000
Mango  1    17.000000
Apple  2    11.500000
       3    12.666667
Mango  4    12.500000
       5     8.666667
Apple  6    13.000000
Mango  7     9.000000
Apple  8    12.400000
       9    12.333333
```

What do we need to do at this point?  Are these averages correct?

And if I use `s.diff().ge(0)` to compare averages you get:

```
Apple  0    0
Mango  1    0
Apple  2    0
       3    1
Mango  4    0
       5    0
Apple  6    1
Mango  7    0
Apple  8    1
       9    0
```

---

IIUC,

Look at this:

```
df.groupby('d1')['c'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1)
```

Output:

```
Apple  0    4.00  #4
Mango  1    6.00  #6
Apple  2    6.50  #9+4 / 2
Mango  3    7.00  #6 + 8 / 2
       4    7.00  #6 + 8 + 7 / 3
       5    7.25  #6 + 8 + 7 + 8 / 4
Apple  6    7.00  #4 + 9 + 8 / 3
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Now, let's compare to previous row:

```
df.groupby('d1')['c'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).diff().ge(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
d1      
Apple  0    0
Mango  1    1
Apple  2    1
Mango  3    1
       4    1
       5    1
Apple  6    0
Name: c, dtype: int32
```

Or maybe you need to compare Mango to last value of apple....

```
df.groupby('d1')['c'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).unstack(0).ffill()
```

Output:

```
d1  Apple  Mango
0     4.0    NaN
1     4.0   6.00
2     6.5   6.00
3     6.5   7.00
4     6.5   7.00
5     6.5   7.25
6     7.0   7.25
```

However, I can't match you expected output:

```
df.groupby('d1')['c'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).unstack(0).ffill().eval('rank= Mango >= Apple')
```

Output:

```
d1  Apple  Mango   rank
0     4.0    NaN  False
1     4.0   6.00   True
2     6.5   6.00  False
3     6.5   7.00   True
4     6.5   7.00   True
5     6.5   7.25   True
6     7.0   7.25   True
```

Comment: Just to explain, incrementally slice the ```DF``` and at every point ```groupby``` the DF by column ```d1``` and find the mean of column ```C``` and replace the value of column ```d1``` based on the rank with grouped mean.

Comment: In the first solution, it does not work for all the cases, I tried again with an another random DF it did not work. I have edited the question to include the example.

Comment: Okay.. I am thoroughly confused.   I think I have the averages calculated the way you need them.  I don't think I undersrand the ranking/comparison you are doing.

Comment: @vikky  Okay see updated solution with new dataframe.  Are the averages correct at this point?

Comment: At the last index, average is ```12.33``` for apple whereas for Mango its ```9.0``` so the value of rank is ```1``` for Apple whereas the solution produces ```0```

Comment: @Vikky... still confused.  Can you go row by row and explain the 0s and 1s? With the new dataframe ending 12.33 for apple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217626/discussion-between-scott-boston-and-vikky).